# npm install into a subfolder

Tags: node.js, npm

How can I run `npm install` in subfolder via command line (single command) if pointer in the main folder and must remain there?

```
main_folder <- pointer is here
  - node_modules
  - package.json
 sub_folder <- npm install here
   - node_modules 
   - package.json
```

Comment: `cd sub_folder && npm i && cd ../`

Comment: Yep, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

With the `prefix` argument you can specify an installation location:

```
npm install --prefix <sub_folder> <module_to_install>
```